# Exception while configuring ruby on rails app on IIS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iis

I have a Windows server 2012 R2 and I downloaded and installed Ruby Hosting Packing from Microsoft Web Platform installer. When I try to run an existing website, I get the following error:

Error

Helicon Zoo module has caught up an error. Please see the details below.

Worker Status

The process was created

Windows error

The pipe has been ended. (ERROR CODE: 109)

Internal module error

message: Application backend read Error. type: ZooException file: App\Jobs\JobBase.cpp line: 531 version: 3.1.98.538

STDERR

[tid-5360004] Couldn't run bundler/setup: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (String) [tid-5360004] cannot load such file -- rack (LoadError) C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:84:in `eval' C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require' (eval):1:in `assure_rack' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:84:in`eval' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:84:in `assure_rack' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:23:in`build_app' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/app.rb:16:in `initialize' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in`new' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/lib/worker.rb:4:in `initialize' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in`new' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:30:in `<module:Zack>' C:/Zoo/Workers/ruby/zoorack.rb:12:in`'

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `When I try to run an existing website`, can you detail what you do here?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 was EOL:ed 5 years ago. I haven't deployed ruby to IIS (nor would I ever really want to) but that package is extremely out of date and insecure.

Comment: It's a website developed with Ruby and MySQL backend. I just got it from my client to setup on IIS.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 was the one installed by Microsoft web platform installer. Can you please explain me how can I install the newer version of the ruby on windows server?